# dotenv file not readed in node cli script

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, dotenv

I've created a `.env` file inside my node cli script folder. I'm trying to load the variables I've defined inside it by using the `process.env.MY_VARIABLE` but I've noticed that they are undefined.

at the moment this is the code inside the `index.js` file of my cli script

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const fb = require('facebook-chat-api'); 

//debug only 
console.log(process.env.FB_EMAIL, process.env.FB_PWD)

let credentials = { email: process.env.FB_EMAIL, password: process.env.FB_PWD }

fb(credentials, (err, api) => {
     if(err) return console.log(err);
     console.log(api);
});
```

and this is the content of my `.env` file that is in the same directory of package.json file and index.js

```
FB_EMAIL="some@email.com"
FB_PWD="apasswprd"
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you loading the .env file ? This mapping of the .env to the `process.env` doesn't happen automatically. You can have a look on https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv for loading an .env file to you `process.env`.

Another way of doing that is having `FB_EMAIL` and `FB_PWD` in your environment from where you run that cli tool. You could try on your terminal `export FB_EMAIL=****`

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm new to node cli so I was thinking that the `.env` file was loaded automatically when the cli script is runnig. I've installed the `dotenv` npm package and now seems working fine